# tar - command different to 10 years ago?

Tags: bash, command-line

With this question am asking "old rabbits" of Ubuntu resp. of Debian.

Am puzzled by the "newer" use of command tar - I know that 10 years ago it was possible
to tar a file to 1/3 of size or even less ! simply by this :

> tar -zcf filename.tgz filename.extension .

( important is point at end after space ! - this was compressing very strong.)

Now point has no effect any more - instead it has effect of compressing all given files in the current directory together to one bundle ?

Today I only can use tar like this :

> tar -zcf filename.tgz filename.extension

( without space and without point ) - this way the file is only compressed slightly to 2/3 of size ?!

Am I doing something wrong - or has the old feature with tar-command been forgotten about this feature with point after space ?!

Comment: Can you provide some evidence this was true ? That would have been a serious bug not to process `.` to mean the current directory.

Comment: @jlliagre - the point operator had around 2000 to 2002 at least 3 different options as operator - not only to mean the current directory - it makes invisible and some more ... have to dig some old CD to find the code of point operator. In Linux handbook of 1995 was an explanation about point for different purposes. Need some time to dig here ...

Comment: I found no reference about this operator in GNU tar changelog from 1990 to 2004. http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/tar/tar/NEWS?view=markup&content-type=text%2Fvnd.viewcvs-markup&revision=1.83

Comment: @jlliagre - please give me some time until Wednesday.

Comment: While you cannot give `tar` an option for gzip compression level, you can set an environment variable `GZIP=-9` or similar to force `tar` and friends to use higher than default (`-6`) compression. If this was set in your environment this would explain (some) difference in output size.

Comment: @chronitis but would not explain the "point" argument non standard behavior.

Comment: @chronitis - how is option for compression level is used ? is this dependent on file-system ? -7h is not accepted here ?

Comment: `GZIP=-9 tar -zcf output.tgz files...` produces a gzipped tar archive with compression level 9 instead of the default 6. A quick and unscientific test with a directory of source code shows that compared to the defaults, `GZIP=-1` produces a file 120% of the size and `GZIP=-9` a file about 98% of the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Such a syntax has never been documented with `GNU tar`.
2. It would have break compatibility with the established de facto `tar` standard.

Given both of these points, my best guess is either you are confusing this with something else or you were using a customized tar version / wrapper.

Comment: you are right. Have probably to clean my eyes.